# How to route all traffic going to external server ip:port through proxy application on local machine [windows]?

Tags: windows, routes, proxy

I am researching application's network protocol. It has specific ip address that it connects to which has no domain name, so I can't just edit /etc/hosts file.

Basically I have a proxy server application running on my machine and I want to route all traffic to the external ip through the proxy server.

I have tried using route add & netsh portproxies but couldn't get any working solution with them, except just fully blocking connection to the specific ip by using route add command.